# Adjust probability of event to reflect joint probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If there is a probability of event A occurring of 0.4. And given event A's occurrence, event B would later occur at a probability of 0.95. How can the probability of event A be adjusted to account for event B?

For example, event A is the probability of conception. Event B is the probability of embryonic survival. I want to adjust the probability of conception to reflect 5% embryonic mortality, which occurs later.

Is the adjusted probability of event A 0.4/0.95?

Please request more details if this is described poorly, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain in a single sentence the interpretation of your final probability in the conception example? Do you want to know the probability of embryonic survival per copulation?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the conditional probability of A given that the event B occurs?

Comment: @TannerPhillips Yes that is correct. The result of the probability of conception and embryonic mortality is an offspring or no offspring, where the probability of conception is adjusted to allow for a 5% probability of mortality that is applied later. I'm sure the probability of conception should be adjusted upwards (increased) so that the final probability of an offspring occurring is still 40%, even after the 5% embryonic mortality is applied. (it seems too simple that the probability of conception should be adjusted upwards to 45%...)

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you just want a conditional probability, which means you just multiply the probability of the conditional evens together. So P(a)*P(b)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...

What is the probability of conception, given embryotic survival?  Intuitively 1 (always), but let's do the math.

First the overall probability of a surviving embryo, P(S) = P(C) * P(C|S) = 0.4 * 0.95 = 0.38 (or 38%)

Then the probability of conception, given a surviving embryo is 100%

$$P(C|S) = P(S|C) \cdot \frac{P(C)}{P(S)}=0.95 \cdot \frac{0.4}{0.38}=1.000$$

Also, the probability of conception, given no surviving embryo is 3.23%

$$P(C|S') = P(S'|C) \cdot \frac{P(C)}{P(S')}=0.05 \cdot \frac{0.4}{1-0.38}=0.0323$$

Intuitively, it is much lower than the 40% a priori probability, but still greater than zero because of the 5% of a non-surviving embryo.